# Detect the presence of a graphic server on OSX?

Tags: macos

I need to know if my program running on OSX is in a graphic capable environment ?

are we running via ssh through a console only pipe ?

on most unix I would test for DISPLAY in the environment variables, but how do you test this on OSX ?

Comment: Possibly better asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the `loginwindow` process isn't running if OS X is not launched in GUI mode (like when you boot in single user mode or if this is a server you're connecting to via SSH).

So I suppose that if a grep on `loginwindow` returns empty, you know the machine is not in GUI mode, for example:

```
ps auxww | grep "/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow" | grep the_logged_in_username | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'
```

would return the PID of `loginwindow` if the process is launched or return nothing if the process is not launched.

*Note that I have not tested, it's just an idea, I don't know for sure if it works...*

Comment: Wouldn't this provide a positive result if *some* GUI session is running for the specified user? Also, I have my doubts that this is guaranteed by spec somewhere, but who knows...

Comment: No idea - I didn't run any tests, I just thought sharing this idea *could* be helpful... but really I'm not sure.